# fold or collapse all unselected lines for multiple edit in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublimetext4

For example i have this codes :

```
 ... 

 addUserKnob {41 mi_box4 l crop T mcrop4.box}
 addUserKnob {41 mi_boxexpr4 l R -STARTLINE T mcrop4.resetwh}
 addUserKnob {41 mi_crop4 l "frame softness" T mcrop4.softness}
 
 ...

 addUserKnob {41 mi_box5 l crop T mcrop5.box}
 addUserKnob {41 mi_boxexpr5 l R -STARTLINE T mcrop5.resetwh}
 addUserKnob {41 mi_crop5 l "frame softness" T mcrop5.softness}

 ...

 addUserKnob {41 mi_box6 l crop T mcrop6.box}
 addUserKnob {41 mi_boxexpr6 l R -STARTLINE T mcrop6.resetwh}
 addUserKnob {41 mi_crop6 l "frame softness" T mcrop6.softness}

 ...
```

There will be a lot of 'sequential code' like that (i only use 4,5 and 6 for this example). I want to edit multiple lines at the same time. I can use cmd-D to edit multiple. But in my real script those 3 code blocks are separated very far to each other, there are 100 lines between them. So when i do cmd D and do editing, i can't really see all my lines at the same time. Is there any method to hide those in-between codes so folding everything but the codes i'm editing ? Or any better way ?

Answer (score 2):

If the the other code is in blocks that can be folded independently, you can select **`Edit → Code Folding → Fold All`** and then unfold the sections you're interested in.

Another option is to use **`File → New View Into File`** (Sublime Text 3) or **`File → Split View`** (ST4) to create duplicate (or triplicate) views of the same file. These can then be arranged in columns or rows (default is columns) and scrolled independently to see different sections of the file at the same time.